# Invalid namespace in PowerShell working with FSRM

Tags: powershell, namespaces

Trying PS command:

```
Set-FsrmFileGroup -Name "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -IncludePattern @((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://fsrm.experiant.ca/api/v1/combined" -UseBasicParsing).Content | ConvertFrom-Json | % {$_.filters})
```

Getting error:

```
New-FsrmFileGroup : Invalid namespace
At line:1 char:1
+ New-FsrmFileGroup -Name "Anti-Ransomware File Groups" -IncludePattern @((Invoke- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_FSRMFileGroup:Root/Microsoft/...T_FSRMFileGroup) [New-FsrmFileGroup], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004100e,New-FsrmFileGroup
```

I also notice some errors in FSRM:

[image: errors]

Firewall is off and I am domain admin running this as admin. SFC and a WMI repair came back as good. I am going based off a guide (https://fsrm.experiant.ca/). This has worked across a ton of other servers so I don't believe the commands to be improperly formatted.

Output of `Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/Fsrm' -List`:

```
Get-WmiObject : Could not get objects from namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/Fsrm.
Invalid namespace
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/Fsrm' -List
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : INVALID_NAMESPACE_IDENTIFIER,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.G‌​etWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root/Microsoft/Windows/Fsrm' -List`?

Comment: Looks to me like you have just the FSRM management tools installed, but not the actual FSRM role. Try (re-)installing the role.

Comment: Will try that. Also did this because i was getting errors in server manager. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c0adff5-5c1d-48ad-a6ea-fc2276529e31/server-manager-2012-configuration-refresh-failed-with-the-following-error-invalid-class?forum=winservermanager